# Codility doesn't compile C# and VB code that contains HashSet and lambda

Tags: c#, vb.net, compilation

I was trying out Codility today and ran into a compiler issue where it wouldn't allow me to use Hash sets or lambda.

Here is the task that I was asked to do:

> Write a function:
>
> class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
>
> that, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive
>   integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.
>
> For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return
>   5.
>
> Given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4.
>
> Given A = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.
>
> Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:
>
> N is an integer within the range [1..100,000]; each element of array A
>   is an integer within the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000].

My solution in VB was:

```
Private Function solution(A As Integer()) As Integer
    Dim N As Integer = 1
    Dim hash As HashSet(Of Integer) = New HashSet(Of Integer)(A).Where(Function(x) x > 0).ToHashSet
    While hash.Contains(N)
        N += 1
    End While
    Return N
End Function
```

This solution didn't work in Codility it gave me error "VBNC90019". I googled it and found that lambda doesn't compile in the older version of VB. (is Codility out-dated?)

Then I decided to try same approach in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        int N = 1;
        HashSet<int> hash = new HashSet<int>(A).Where(x => x > 0).ToHashSet();
        while(hash.Contains(N))
        {
            N += 1;
        }
        return N;
    }
}
```

Here, it tells me that it cannot find HashSet in Collections..

Am I doing something wrong here? It works just fine in Visual Studio, but it will not compile in Codility.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you want to show source, include it as text in your question.  If you press the `{}` button, the source will be indented 4 spaces and will show up as _code_ in your question (as long as you leave a blank line above and below.

Comment: SO is not right place to ask for support on some product (especially if you can't even link to any information about it)

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks. Got that fixed. I just had screenshots to show an error that it was displaying.

Comment: [Codility](https://www.codility.com/) appears to be a recruiter tool - _"Codility is a software platform that helps tech recruiters and hiring managers assess their candidates' skills by testing their code online."_ - ugh

Comment: Maybe is telling you that `HashSet<int>()` doesn't have a definition for `Where()`, because `System.Linq` is not referenced. `HashSet<>().ToHashset()` is not great either. You should probably move that `Where()` clause...